# How to pass parameters through Ionic 4 tabs buttons

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, angular7, progressive-web-apps, ionic4

How to pass parameters through Ionic 4 tabs buttons

```html
    <ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab-bar slot="top" color="light">
      <ion-tab-button tab="tab1">
        <ion-label> Tab 1 </ion-label>
      </ion-tab-button>
      <ion-tab-button tab="tab2">
        <ion-label> Tab 2 </ion-label>
      </ion-tab-button>
    </ion-tab-bar>
  </ion-tabs>
```

In my tabsmain.module.ts am routing each of these as

```js
    const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: TabsmainPage, children: [
      { path: '', loadChildren: './pages/tab1/tab1.module#Tab1PageModule' },
      { path: 'tab1/:id2', loadChildren: './pages/tab1/tab1.module#Tab1PageModule' },
      { path: 'tab2', loadChildren: './pages/tab2/tab2.module#Tab2PageModule' }},
    ]
  }
];
```

I want to pass some ID as a parameter as we do through NavParams
Please help me, How I can pass parameters through ***ion-tab-button***

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question... are you looking for something like this?: https://i.gyazo.com/b963d4a0c173a69a3c9ddf0291a2d4c6.mp4

Comment: Yes exactly like this.

Comment: Can i send parameters through tabs navigation as we can pass parameters through Angular 7 routing.

Comment: I've just added an answer with the code

Answer (score 4):

Please find below the steps to build something like this:

[image: tabs-demo]

---

First I created a brand new `tabs` app using `ionic start` command and then updated the `tabs.router.module.ts` file to allow the `tab2` to receive an `id` as parameter:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'tab1',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../tab1/tab1.module#Tab1PageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
    {
        path: 'tab2',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../tab2/tab2.module#Tab2PageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      // ---------------- START: Added by me  ----------------
      {
        path: 'tab2/:id',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../tab2/tab2.module#Tab2PageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      // ---------------- END: Added by me  ----------------
      {
        path: 'tab3',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../tab3/tab3.module#Tab3PageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}
```

Once that's done, I've updated the `tabs1` page like this:

**Component**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: "app-tab1",
  templateUrl: "tab1.page.html",
  styleUrls: ["tab1.page.scss"]
})
export class Tab1Page {
  public items: Array<{ id: number; name: string }> = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Item 1"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Item 2"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Item 3"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "Item 4"
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: "Item 5"
    }
  ];

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  public onOpenItem(item: any) {
    this.router.navigate([`tabs/tab2/${item.id}`]);
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Tab One
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="onOpenItem(item)" detail=”true”>
      <ion-label>{{item.name}}</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

As you can see there, the only *important* thing is that when the user clicks on an item, the `onOpenItem(...)` method will change the selected tab because of this line:

```
this.router.navigate([`tabs/tab2/${item.id}`]);
```

Then the last thing left to be done is to update the `tabs2` page to get the `id` parameter from the url, like this:

**Component**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: "app-tab2",
  templateUrl: "tab2.page.html",
  styleUrls: ["tab2.page.scss"]
})
export class Tab2Page {

  public id: number;

  constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Tab Two
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <h2>The selected id is: {{ id }}</h2>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: I have used this method for multiple tabs, but selected tab is not focused, when i remove the dynamic ids focus returns